# Redirect a new page from server

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have this WebMethod that redirects to another page on that server.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public static Boolean realizaConsulta(Dictionary<string, string> datos)
{
    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("PRepConsulta.aspx", false);
}
```

But i get this error:

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException:
>   The server method 'realizaConsulta' failed with the following error:
>   System.InvalidOperationException-- Authentication failed.

What causes this error?

---

look the other options i have tried:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public static Boolean realizaConsulta(Dictionary<string, string> datos)
        {
           System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("PRepConsulta.aspx", false);
        }
```

IT WORKS, BECAUSE, IT GOES TO PRepConsulta.aspx AND EXECUTE THE UNDERCODE, BUT THE PAGE NEVER SHOWS UP.

I HAVE ALSO TRIED:

```
        [WebMethod]
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
        public static Boolean realizaConsulta(Dictionary<string, string> datos)
        {
               HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("PRepConsulta.aspx", false);
        }
```

BUT I GOT THIS ERROR:

Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.Net.WebServiceFailedException: The server method 'realizaConsulta' failed with the following error: System.Threading.ThreadAbortException-- Subproceso anulado.

I DONT KNOW WHAT ELSE TO TRY

THANKS FOR ANY HELP

Comment: What is you goal for calling the WebMethod? Do you want to display additional content or send the user to an appropriate page based on data you are passing?

You're probably better off just passing the data in a query string to a new page and redirecting from there.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about the "authentication failed" part, but a Response.Redirect inside of a WebMethod is probably going to break the SOAP client that's calling the method.  It's expecting a Boolean, not a redirect.

Comment: For lack of a better place to put this reply... It sounds like you're not actually telling the browser to redirect.  However you've wired up the JavaScript to call the web service, it's calling it and receiving something other than a boolean (which is what it expects).  The context of the SOAP call to the web service is different than the context of the web page at which you're looking.  At no point is the browser being told to redirect to another page, instead it's just calling a SOAP method and receiving an unexpected response.  The redirect logic is in the wrong place, basically.

Answer (score 0):

ok, im gonna organize the application's flow:

from my client, in javascript, im calling a web service

PageMethods.realizaConsulta(Datos);

in my codebehind i have to execute the pageMethod and call another page

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Xml)]
public static Boolean realizaConsulta(Dictionary<string, string> datos)
{

    clsGeneral consulta;
    DataTable dtTemp = new DataTable();

    using (consulta = new clsGeneral("SQLConn"))
    {
        consulta.consultaPrograma(ref dtTemp, datos["Codigo"],  Int16.Parse(datos["Cod_Actividad"]), Int16.Parse(datos["Cod_SubActividad"]), datos["FechaIni"], datos["FechaFin"]);
        HttpContext.Current.Session["Consulta"] = dtTemp;

    //THIS ARE THE 3 DIFFERENT WAYS I HAVE TRIED TO CALL THE PRepConsulta.aspx,
    //I DONT KNOW IF THERE IS A BETTHER WAY TO DO IT

    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("PRepConsulta.aspx", false);
    //HttpContext.Current.Server.Transfer("PRepConsulta.aspx", false);
    //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("PRepConsulta.aspx",writer, false);
    }
    return true;
}
```

THANKS

Comment: The redirect is really just in the wrong place in this design.  If the user is _always_ redirected to the other page, then you'll probably want to either: 1) Redirect the user from the JavaScript to a new page and call this logic on that page's load; 2) Place the redirect in the JavaScript after the call to this WebMethod returns.  Putting the redirect in the WebMethod doesn't tell the browser to redirect, it just breaks the return value.

Comment: Well,, thats how I did it in the beggining, i was calling the webMethod and after that, i was calling the new page by window.open function, but, when i uploaded the project into the server, i realized that the window opens before the webMethod ends.

The webMethod runs a query and i keep the result into a session variable, and i use it in the window that i open next.

thats why i tried to open the window from the server, because i need to be sure, that the query has already run and the result is in my session variable.

Comment: Sounds like you're calling the WebMethod asynchronously.  Surely there's a way to wait for the return, check the value, and respond accordingly (with either a redirect or an error message).  Also, is there a specific reason this WebMethod is being called via JavaScript in the first place?  There seems to be some bigger picture influencing this design that isn't clear here.

Comment: ok i solved it, as you said, im excecuting another function based on the response:

PageMethods.realizaConsulta(Datos, onLoadDatos);

function onLoadDatos(response){
            if(response){ 
              window.open('http://www.website.com/');}
            else{alert("error")}
}

thanks for your answers!!